# |+ operators in getops of ksh

Tags: linux, database, ksh, getopts

What is difference when we use |+ operator in getopts of ksh ?

Examples of code are

```
while getopts d: o
do  case "$o" in
    d|+d)   seplist="$OPTARG";;
    esac
done

echo $seplist
```

and

```
while getopts d: o
do  case "$o" in
    d)  seplist="$OPTARG";;
    esac
done

echo $seplist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator `|` means *or*, so `d|+d)` means `d` or `+d`.